# JQGrid: colmodel name collision

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I'm passing rich, nested domain objects for jqgrid to display as flat data rows. I'm doing this because I want to avoid the need to create a flat java Data Transfer Object for each of the 100++ data grids in my application. Sample row data:

```xml
<record>
  <brand>
    <description>The Brand</description> 
    <brandId>305</brandId> 
  </brand>
  <description>The description</description> 
  <recordId>110</recordId>  
</record>
```

Unfortunately this creates a naming collision between the 2  elements: the brand description column displays fine, but the root description column displays both 'descriptions' concatenated ('TheBrandThe description'). Here's my column model:

```js
colModel :
    {name:'brand>description', index:"brand>brandId",
        xmlmap:"brand>description",width:200},
    {name:'description', index:'description', xmlmap:"description",
        editable:true, edittype:'text', width:500} 
]
```

How should I modify the column model, so that there is no collision between the 2 'descriptions'? I tried to use xmlmap but nothing changed. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you should do is the following

1. you should start `xmlmap` with `>` symbol to specify the path from the root of XML item.
2. you should use values of `name` properties of `colModel` which corresponds to properties names. For example `name: 'brand'` or `name: "brand_description"` instead of `name:'brand>description'`.
3. you should better don't specify any `index` property for column description. In the case jqGrid will copy internally the value of `name` property to `index`.

[The demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/user2309409.htm) shows the results. It uses

```js
colNames: ["brandId", "brand description", "description", "recordId"],
colModel: [
    { name: "brand_brandId", xmlmap: ">brand>brandId", key: true, width: 100},
    { name: "brand_description", xmlmap: ">brand>description", width: 200},
    { name: "description", xmlmap: ">description", editable: true, width: 500},
    { name: "recordId", width: 100}
]
```

I added additionally `key: true` to the definition of `">brand>brandId"` because I supposed that the value is unique for every item and it can be used as rowid. You can choose `id` of the rows in another way of cause.

Comment: Thank you Oleg! This part didn't work for me: root: ">records", row: ">record" (in xmlReader), so I removed the '>' characters, but the changes in colModel worked fine. One more question if that's ok: what do I need to change in colModel if I decide to use JSON data instead of XML?

Comment: @user2309409: You don't posted **full XML** file which you use so I don't know whether `root: ">records", row: ">record"` are correct settings in your case. In my demo `records` is *root* element of XML file and `record` root of XML item. I recommend you use JSON instead of XML. You could need `jsonmap: "brand.description"` instead of `xmlmap: ">brand>description"`.

Comment: Ok, I'll check it out. And you are right my XML file has one more level on top .. Thanks again for your help.